# How to run django local host and activate virtual env by using single command?

Tags: django, cmd

I M New to Django, Whenever I open my project, everyday i type CMD to activate virtual env then, to open local server i use runserver, but I want to open my local host by using single command. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Make a shell script?

Comment: Do you have any shell script to do that @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: For a linux machine, yes. But since you mention "cmd", I assume you do not work on a Linux machine :)

Comment: are you using Linux or windows?

Comment: windows @TanveerHasan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run command using shell script you have to open text editor and write your desired command. then save it as .bat file. It will create a executable file and simply use double click to run it. if you have multiple command use '&' between them. 
**Example**

```
cd your directory &
python manage.py runserver
```